# OOzie hive script action capture output to a file on locla or hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, oozie, oozie-workflow

I have a hive script which is a select query triggered using oozie , how to i configure oozie to write the output of the hive script to a file on hdfs.

I do not want to use INSERT OVERWRITE option.

Is there an easy way where I can tell oozie to save the output to so and so location  .

Comment: Oozie is used for scheduling. It is not meant for performing data operations. You can pass arguments to hive script about the output location. Still you have `fs action` available. You can check if it suits your requirement.

Comment: Hive is already on HDFS, and `INSERT OVERWRITE` is the correct way to do what you want... Oozie shouldn't be necessary other than running your job on a regular basis